# Typescript type for any non-array values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to make a specific type that matches anything except for arrays, for use with `extends` as a constraint on a generic value?

Things that don't work:

```ts
type NotArrayExplicit = Exclude<any, any[]>;
const shouldFail: NotArrayExplicit = [1,2,3];
// ^ Permitted by typechecker (opposite of desired behavior)

// This works for generics, yet can't be used with <T extends NotArrayGeneric>
type NotArrayGeneric<T> = T & Exclude<T, Array<any>>;
const rejectSuccess: NotArrayGeneric<number[]> = [1,2,3,4];
//                                                ^ Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

function thisDoesntWork<T extends NotArrayGeneric<T>>(nonArray: T): T {return nonArray;}
//                                ^ Error: Type parameter 'T' has a circular constraint
```

[Playground for above code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=88#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)

The goal type is something that can be used as a constraint on a generic type, like `<T extends NonArray>`, in a clean and idiomatic way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this, but you a workaround to make sure you're not getting a array value is putting the NotArrayGeneric type as the type of the param you want.

```
type NotArrayGeneric<T> = T & Exclude<T, Array<unknown>>;

function example<T>(nonArray: NotArrayGeneric<T>): T {
    return nonArray;
}

example(1) // this works
example([1]) // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

example({a: 1}) // this works
example([{a: 1}]) // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```